# Type mismatch, when passing arugment to Model Class

Tags: java, kotlin

The problem is when I created the instance of my Model class and pass the non-nullable variable to the constructor, the compiler shows the error Type-mismatch.
I have fixed the type-mismatch error by making model class variable as nullable

But I couldn't understand the error shown by the compiler.

Model class

```
class SharedPreferenceEntry (val name:String, val dateOfBirth:Calendar, val email:String)
```

Helper class SharedPreferencesHelper, where I created an instance of Model class and return that instance from function

```
fun getPersonalInfo(): SharedPreferenceEntry { // Get data from the SharedPreferences.
        val name = mSharedPreferences.getString(KEY_NAME, "")
        val dobMillis =
            mSharedPreferences.getLong(KEY_DOB, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
        val dateOfBirth: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        dateOfBirth.setTimeInMillis(dobMillis)
        val email = mSharedPreferences.getString(KEY_EMAIL, "")
        // Create and fill a SharedPreferenceEntry model object.
        return SharedPreferenceEntry(name, dateOfBirth, email)
    }
```

Comment: `val email` is most probably a nullable string because `mSharedPreferences.getString(..)` returns a nullable. And in the constructor of `SharedPreferenceEntry` you have declared `email` to be non-nullable. That's the type mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sonnet commented, the use of `mSharedPreferences.getString(...)` will return `null` if the key is mapped to `null`.  To ensure, the value of `mSharedPreferences.getString(...)` is non-null, change it to `mSharedPreferences.getString(...) ?: ""`.